# What purpose of this code pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am debugging somebody else's code and I just don't understand the benefit of coding this way in Java.

I am not a Java Design Pattern expert but I would like to know when is this applicable?

```
public class MyClass {

    public static class Builder {
        //Getters and setters
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    public MyClass(Builder builder) {
        //More Methods
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass.Builder builder = MyClass.newBuilder();
        new MyClass(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a poorly implemented builder pattern. Or maybe it was correctly implemented and you just left out the relevant parts. Although the constructor taking the builder as a parameter looks so stupid that it was probably implemented by someone who wasn't a "Java Design Pattern expert" either.

Comment: @Kayaman I actually put the main method myself.  I cannot think of a way to instantiate this class without doing what I did in my main method right?  There are lots of moving code that will clutter my question so I stripped lots of it.

Comment: In a proper builder pattern you don't have access to the constructor, the only way to create an instance is through the builder object (with some `build()` method).

Comment: @Kayaman I was curious.. so the following is considered wrong also? https://www.mkyong.com/design-pattern/java-builder-design-pattern-example/  I think this is the pattern that the code that I am looking at is following.

Comment: @Kayaman, I am not sure if my accepted answer is correct also.. because even his code is accepting a builder in the constructor.

Comment: The whole idea of the builder pattern is to provide a more flexible alternative to the constructor, making the constructor call look odd here. Passing the builder to a constructor does allow you to build in parts before constructing the object, but calling the constructor directly prevents the builder from returning different implementing classes for example. So no, that's not something you could consider a *correct* builder pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This an implementation with few wrongs settings of [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

> The intent of the Builder design pattern is to separate the construction of a complex object from its representation. By doing so the same construction process can create different representations.

What is strange here is that the constructor of the `Builder` class is called from `MyClass`. This is not generally done because ties the `MyClass` class to the `Builder` and not viceversa.

Additionally `MyClass` constructor should be `private` so that nobody can't access it directly, but only using the `Builder`.

The right implementation should be as follow:

```
public class MyClass {
    // Often fields are final to create an immutable class
    private final String fieldA;

    // Private constructor using Builder to set inner fields
    // To create MyClass you have to use Builder
    private MyClass(Builder builder) {
        // Setting fields from builder
        this.a = builder.getFieldA();
    }

    public static class Builder {
       // Fields on Builder are not final
       private String fieldA;

       //Getters and setters

       // Method to set field of builder
       public Builder setFieldA(String a) {
          this.a = a;
          return this;   // Returning this to chain setters
       }

    ...
        // Method to instantiate MyClass
        public MyClass build() {
           return new MyClass(this);
        }
    }
}

// Calling it as follow
MyClass a = new MyClass.Builder()
                .setFieldA("value")
                .setFieldB("value")
                .build();
```

Comment: From the comment above... having a constructor with a builder as parameter can be considered a bad practice? Is this correct?

Comment: No is not. Is a bad practice having a method to get the builder in MyClass

Answer (score 2):

According to the naming, this looks like one of the creational patterns - Builder pattern. However, this one is not well implemented.

The purpose of this pattern is to write readable and clean code to create a very complex object. A good and yet simple example is [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). It is often implemented with a fluent interface - a typical example is [`Stream<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

The correct implementation is for example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern). It allows you to create an object using methods returning the builder. Example:

```
MyClass foo = MyClass.newBuilder()
    .cached()
    .with(new Feature1())
    .with(new Feature2())
    .foo()
    .bar()
    .build();
```

My personal point of view to this pattern:

> It encourages to create and use complex objects. I prefer to refactor an object which has a builder with the smaller components. The object becomes easily testable and creatable through the constructors only.

Answer (score 1):

The Builder pattern exposes what's called a Fluent API. Rather than individual set calls on each line, you can chain setters followed by a final build method to get the class instance. There's not typically getters on a builder object.

That constructor is a form of a copy constructor. I'm guessing there's other code using it to build unique instances of an object with the same data.

The last line of your main method isn't doing anything since you're not assigning that new class. In any case, as mentioned, you'd typically use a build method, not pass the builder into a constructor

```
MyClass foo = MyClass.newBuilder()
    .withBar("blah")
    .build();
```

`MyClass.newBuilder()` could also be replace by `new MyClass.Builder()`